# Python Flask Base64 Images "Error: Incorrect padding" - only in safari

Tags: python, flask, safari, base64

I am resizing images by drawing them into a canvas and getting its data url.

In my python I use the data url to decode the image:

```
content = form.dataurl_main.data.split(';')[1]
image_encoded = content.split(',')[1]
body = base64.decodestring(image_encoded.encode('utf-8'))
```

It works absolutely fine in chrome and firefox, but in safari I get this error:

[image]

```
2017-03-28T11:33:39.293926+00:00 app[web.1]:     return func(*args, **kwargs)
2017-03-28T11:33:39.293931+00:00 app[web.1]:     body = base64.decodestring(image_encoded.encode('utf-8'))
2017-03-28T11:33:39.293933+00:00 app[web.1]:     return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
2017-03-28T11:33:39.293933+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Incorrect padding
2017-03-28T11:33:39.293932+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/base64.py", line 328, in decodestring
```

It seems that it fails to get the correct dataurl, probably the data url looks different if it is generated in safari, here is my JS how I create the data url:

My canvas and data url TextField:

```
<canvas class="make-display-none" id="uploading_canvas_main" name="uploading_canvas_main"></canvas>
{{ form.dataurl_main(class="make-display-none") }}
```

The JS:

```
$( "input#hauptbild" ).change(function() {

var filesToUpload = this.files;

var img_m = document.createElement("img");
img_m.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);

$( img_m ).load(function() {

    canvas = $("#uploading_canvas_main").get(0);                    

    var MAX_WIDTH = 550;
    var MAX_HEIGHT = 400;
    var width = img_m.width;
    var height = img_m.height;

    if (width > height) {
      if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
        height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
        width = MAX_WIDTH;
      }
    } else {
      if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
        width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
        height = MAX_HEIGHT;
      }
    }       

    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img_m, 0, 0, width, height);

    var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");

    $( "#dataurl_main" ).val(dataurl);

    });
});
```

**EDIT**

Here are the last few characters from `print image_encoded`:

```
... x/AsXcAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

I tryed removing the last two characters:

```
if image_encoded[-2:] == "==":
    image_encoded = image_encoded[:-2]
```

But then I got the padding error in chrome.
In safari I had no error anymore but the image didnt uploaded.

Comment: Could you post the output of `print(image_encoded)`. A padding error is usually easy to solve by adding or removing `==` at the end of the base64 code. Also, as good practice: please remove the IMG containing the error code and paste the actual code. This is also to prevent the image from becoming a dead-link some time in the future.

Comment: There are really two ==, so these have to be removed?

Comment: if I remove the two == I get the same error on chrome

Comment: And with Safari?

Comment: PS: If you have encoded the image yourself, try doing so by using [image2py](https://github.com/mezgani/gomoz/blob/master/Gomoz/share/image2py.py) so you can be sure it is properly encoded. If the encoding went wrong, decoding it won't work.

Comment: If I removed == I am not getting an error anymore in safari but the image is not uploaded. I am getting padding error in chrome.

Comment: If I leave == I am getting padding error in safari, works fine in chrome and firefox

Comment: Seems like something isn't water-tight in your encoding. I updated the link to a newer version of image2py, so you could try to use that to encode your image and see if the problems persist..

Comment: Oops, no the update doesn't work, so here is the new link: [link](http://www.filedropper.com/img2pyfile). It's a copy of the version I am using uploaded to filedropper.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I managed to solve the issue (but do not understand why it solved it, if someone can evaluate a bit further it would help).

The problem here is the `form.dataurl_main.data` aka. `dataurl` itself (general the image data itself).

It could be that the data url is somehow to short if generated in safari.
But adding the string `"SAFARI"` (would probably work with any random string) to the dataurl if in safari browser solved the issue:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.search("Safari") >= 0 && navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") < 0) {
    $( "#dataurl_main" ).val("SAFARI" + dataurl);
} else {
    $( "#dataurl_main" ).val(dataurl);
}
```

In my code I am slicing out the image data, so actually the added string does not affect the imagedata, but it seems that the general datastring is then valid?

Anyway with this piece of code I made several tests and it worked in all browsers without failing.